# Is it possible to extract both the color and the depth texture from one RenderTexture and use it in a Shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, depth-buffer, rendertexture

I can access the same with duplicating the cameras AND the rendertextures, but that seems like a lot of overkill of just getting the depth buffer.

I don't need a very precise depth buffer, so it can easily be put in the alpha channel.

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question: "put depth in the alpha channel". What happens when you try this?

Comment: Hi @DMGregory, I only see one "depth" setting with ColorFormat on the RenderTexture - and that is called Auto Depth and puts it in the color channels. So then it doesn't write any colors anymore.

Comment: So write a shader that puts depth where you want it while rendering the colour components, or use a post process to copy the depth texture into the alpha channel? What step do you need help with?

Comment: if I need both the depth and the color channels then I need to have two cameras (camera can only write to one rendertexture) and two render passes. I will take a look at postprocesses (but I am still using the legacy pipeline)

Comment: No, Unity also writes a specially-named depth texture that you can read from while the camera is rendering (and I think in OnRenderImage just after it's finished). [Here's an older presentation about it that describes how to use it in the legacy pipeline](https://blog.unity.com/community/special-effects-with-depth-talk-at-siggraph).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll take a more extended look tonight